# p2pool merged mining

Tags: p2pool, mining-reward, merged-mining, vertcoin

I installed p2pool on my server for triple merged mining - VTC, MON, PLX. Server is running smoothly, but I don'know how to setup my addreses in miner. I have read that you can add for example MON address in password field, but what if you mining more than two coins, where put the addresses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You actually don't use the addresses, but the RPC info for the daemons. For example you'd start the pool with the following switches:

```
python run_p2pool.py --net vertcoin3 --merged http://*RPCuser1*:*LongRPCpass1*@127.0.0.1:6888 --merged http://*RPCuser2*:*LongRPCpass*2@127.0.0.1:7817
```

You will see "Got new merged mining work!" in console as confirmation.